# Join 2 column same table with another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join 2 column that share same foreign key in another table

here's the tables:

```
country:
idcountry| countryname
 1         german
 2         america
```

destination

```
id|fromcountry    |tocountry
1  1               2
```

the result that i wanted to:

```
id|fromc    |toc
1  german    america
```

Comment: This could be nice article for you to start with [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Use simple Left Join ans provide alias to country name column:

```
SELECT d.idcountry as id, cf.CountryName as fromc, ct.CountryName as toc
FROM destination d
LEFT JOIN country cf ON d.fromcountry = cf.idcountry
LEFT JOIN country ct ON d.tocountry = ct.idcountry
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Outer Join for both fields
something like this

```
SELECT Dest.ID, CFrom.CountryName, CTo.CountryName
FROM Destination Dest 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Country CFrom ON Dest.FromCountry = CFrom.idcountry
LEFT OUTER JOIN Country CTo ON Dest.ToCountry = CTo.idcountry
```